# Read JSON code over API and post on Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have a short question - I have an API where I have multiple JSON entrys. I got them with:

```
$json = file_get_contents('xxx');
```

Decoded them with

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

and stored them here

```
    $id = $data ['xx']['0']['id'];
$title = $data ['xx']['0']['title'];
$description = $data ['xx']['0']['description'];
```

and I got an DB connection like that

```
    $mysqlDatabaseName ='test';
$mysqlUserName ='root';
$mysqlPassword ='';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());
```

Question I have now is, how can I upload the full 200 articles stored with json on my database. It works fine with one, but I guess I have to use JS? Help would be great. thx

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead

Comment: Why us `JS`? you are using `PHP`! were you able to insert this 1 record in DB? if so, you have to be able to insert the rest of 199 records as-well.